# Traversing over table rows adding a class

Tags: jquery, html-table, keypress

I have a table such as the follows:

```
<table border="1" width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr class="keydown"> <!-- Should this be a class? when down arrow is pressed class="selected" should be applied to this-->
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="keydown">
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

As the down arrow key is pressed (ascii 40?? or 31?) I want the first row in the table to be selected, i.e. a class should be applied to it highlight (i.e. change in bg colour) it. When the down arrow key is pressed again it should go to the next row. Is there a plugin for this? I'm messing around with jQuery but I'm a completely new at this.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {     
    $('#keydown').keypress(function() {
        $("#keydown").addClass("selected");
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: You should definitely use a class instead of id when marking multiple elements.

Comment: That `<table>` is illegal, as you are not allowed to repeat IDs.  IDs are one-off identifiers, use a class where you need to repeat it.

Comment: Element IDs **must** be unique, so yes, **change `id="keydown"` to `class="keydown"`**.

Comment: Ok, I'll change the code, thanks.

Comment: You'll be much better off using using one of the many jQuery table plugins out there. [jQuery Tableselect](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tableSelect) might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to use keyup for things like this, which key information is stored in the event argument. Also, your document ready isn't correct:

```
$(function() { // or use: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.keydown').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === '40')
            $(this).addClass('selected');
    }); 
});
```